# WPF consumer with ServiceStack using openid

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, servicestack

We have a servicestack webservice which is authenticated using openid
and the client is a wpf app, trying to use openid/oauth and have questions

Is is possible to authenticate the wpf client using oauth2 and use the auth tokens to authenticate with the servicestack webservice ?

Assuming that the user will have to 1st login to the website using openid and the openid/emailid/name etc will be stored locally in the website and subsequently used to map roles/authorizations when used by the wpf client ?

Is this the right approach or likely i have it all mixed up ?

Looking for any sample/example of how to make this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach seems right to me and you can use this library, used it once and it is very good.

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: thanks, it looks like servicestack has a client JsonServiceClient which could handle the openid auth out of the box - still looking though !

Comment: Just one small question, are you going to use rest web services? If so why not use the new ASP.net API instead? http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: all samples for that seem to use azure client services, it's probably possible to use it without, also haven't found any example of my usage scenario above involving wpf client